# Creating Dynamic Book Dashboard in Notion: Seeking Help for Real-time Book Collection Insights

Tags: visualization, data-analysis, notion, notion-js

I have a book database in Notion, and the properties with sample data are as follows:

| Name | Author | Completed | Cover | Current Page | Description | Expected Reading Speed | Formula | Genre | Price | Progress | Rating | Status | Summary | Tags | Total Pages | Quotes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Midnight’s Children | Salman Rushdie |  |  |  |  | Quick Escapes | 0 | Genre |  |  | ★★★★★ | To Read | Summary | Tags | 45 | To Buy Author writes in magic realism. Need to explore that part too. |
| The Black Swan | Nassim Nicholas Taleb (https://www.notion.so/Nassim-Nicholas-Taleb-1ab3f84797e949fea4083ed5?pvs=21) |  | [link](https://stackoverflow.com) | 50 | all about black swam events | Steady Progress | 0 | Finances (https://www.notion.so/Finances-d9cd677500fb47199a08ea1b33?pvs=21) |  | 0.1 | ★★★★★ | Reading | "My views: Black swan events can dramatically disrupt our lives and we probably won’t see the next one coming! |  | 445 | The inability to predict outliers implies the inability to predict the course of history, given the share of these events in the dynamics of the events. (https://www.notion.so/The-inability-to-predict-outliers-implies-the-inability-to-predict-the-course-of-history-given-the--08e91f?pvs=21), You will accumulate more knowledge and more books as you grow older, and the growing number of unread books on the shelves will look at you menacingly. (https://www.notion.so/You-will-accumulate-more-knowledge-and-more-books-as-you-grow-older-and-the-growing-number-of-unrea-7d40c3962051bd19?pvs=21), Ideas come and go, stories stay (https://www.notion.so/Ideas-come-and-go-stories-stay-bfd3464dcc7d?pvs=21) |

In this database, I can easily calculate counts, but I'm struggling with creating values like `number of books read,` `number of books not read,` `number of books to buy,` and `total money spent on books.` These values are not linked to any other place, and I'd like to have a widget on the dashboard that can display this information in real-time. I want to make the dashboard more informative and user-friendly for tracking my book collection.

[image]

As shown in the picture these values are attached to the database which can't be taken or copied or ditto the values at any other place inside the notion page or inside the sub-page. To get this data there is just one way that to add a view of the whole sheet.

Expected Dashboard on the notion page should look something like this:

Imagine, the sub-headings and titles of the each category in the notion page as per my database properties.
[image]

I did try using the relation and roll-up feature in the notion. But that only works in the column wise not row wise.

You can get the information on how the relation & roll-up works at this [link](https://www.notion.so/help/relations-and-rollups)

The current dashboard of my notion page looks like:

https://joypal.notion.site/J-s-Shelf-6a3fe53c46474910a32daae76b4c7845?pvs=4

Comment: The graphs in the expected image are not actually needed but if there is a way to actually get on notion, I think that will be cool

Comment: Did you try using external integrations? Like i hear there are few notion widget tools online.

Comment: @codeapplied I did look into those sites,  they have pre-build widgets like clock, calendar as such. But none are actually useful to link to the database get the insights.

Comment: The feature your looking at is not yet introduced on the notion. There are few feature request i saw in notion forum.

Comment: True @codeapplied but I thought someone would have figured a way through this issue and get my desired output. It really makes sense when we use such productive tool in the market which is so famous with lot of editable, manageable databases included.

Comment: I could migrate to other tools with the data i have but I loose the ability to use notion and will disappointed to let go other features which i get through this tool